# Returning Sorted JSON with bottle.py

Tags: python, json, bottle

I'm building an API with bottle.py and would like to return jsons that are sorted by key. Here's the code:

```
@route('/test', method='GET')
def sorted():
  return {'z': 'should be last', 'm': 'should be second', 'a': 'should be first'}
```

Unfortunately it returns

```
{"a": "should be first", "z": "should be last", "m": "should be second"}
```

What I hope to return is

```
{"a": "should be first", "m": "should be second", "z": "should be last"}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Python dicts are unordered. JSON objects are unordered. JS objects are unordered. Why do you want this?

Comment: If you need to return things in sorted order, use a list.

Comment: Specifically, with [JSON](http://json.org), an array. E.g., for a sorted, ordered result, it'll have to be `[{"key": "a", "value": "should be first"}, {"key": "m", "value": "should be second"}, {"key": "z", "value": "should be last"}]`

Comment: E.g.: `return sorted(mydict.items(), key=lambda x: x[0])`

Comment: I was thinking of something like the json module's: 
return json.dumps(mydict, sort_keys=True)

Comment: I understand that Python dicts are unordered, but I was hoping I could control the ordering of the JSON object when it's returned to the client. Given your responses, I guess that's not possible. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @niko246 I'm not sure if it'll help at all, but you could always look into `sortedDict`s, or work out some sort of sorting method and apply that to the JSON. I also upvoted to counteract the -1

Comment: niko246, did you ever solve this?  Did my answer below work, or did you find another method?

Answer (score 2):

IIRC, a bottle function may return either a dict *or* a string.  So just return a json string, and let `json.dumps` do the sorting for you:

```
@route('/test')
def sorted():
  d = {'z': 'should be last', 'm': 'should be second', 'a': 'should be first'}
  response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
  return json.dumps(d, sort_keys=True)
```

niko246, you alluded to this very answer in your comment on your own question, but I think perhaps you weren't aware that you could return a string.

Comment: But then Bottle.py does not add the json content-type

Comment: @Prof.Falken Thanks, good point - I've updated the answer to set content-type.